# Upgrade from Drupal 7/ CiviCRM 4.6.38 to Drupal 9 / CiviCRM 5.37.2

Tags: drupal, upgrade, export

Good morning ladies and gentlemen,
I would like to upgrade my old installation of CiviCRM on an old system (Drupal 7, CiviCRM 4.6.38 ) to an up to date system like Drupal 9 / CiviCRM 5.37.2. Are there any suggestions how to do that including migration of all data? CSV export?  Mysql-dump (which tables?). I am very open minded (Wordpress instead?) and experienced hacking the shit out of my system. Just looking for a best practice solution.
Thanks for your help,
Robert

Answer (score 2):

If you have a very simple d7 front end with minimum common modules than it won't be difficult to upgrade from d7 >> d8 >> d9.

To Upgrade Civi i would do incremental upgrade i.e

- 4.6 > 4.7(latest)
- 4.7 > 5.8(latest)
- 5.8 > 5.22(latest)
- 5.22 > 5.37(latest)

Would upgrade Civi first than drupal.